# RegEx Match can end with different words

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a few lines, but they can end different. With "Registrar:" or "Registered:".

So I naive tried this:

```
Registrant's address:(\s*)(?<Value>.*).*((Registrar:)|(Registered:))
```

What do I wrong with this OR Operator?

(The goal is to leach data from different tlds with RegEx directly from the WhoIs Server)

**1. Data:**

> Domain name:
>           argos.co.uk
>
> ```
> Registrant:
>     Argos Ltd
>
> Registrant type:
>     UK Public Limited Company, (Company number: 1081551)
>
> Registrant's address:
>     Avebury
>     489-499 Avebury Boulevard
>     Central Milton Keynes
>     Milton Keynes
>     MK9 2NW
>     United Kingdom
>
> Registered through:
>     NetNames Limited
>     URL: http://www.netnames.co.uk
> ```

I want this:

> ```
>     Avebury
>     489-499 Avebury Boulevard
>     Central Milton Keynes
>     Milton Keynes
>     MK9 2NW
>     United Kingdom
> ```

**2. Data:**

> ```
> Domain name:
>     amazon.co.uk
>
> Registrant:
>     Amazon Europe Holding Technologies SCS
>
> Registrant type:
>     Unknown
>
> Registrant's address:
>     65 boulevard G-D. Charlotte
>     Luxembourg City
>     Luxembourg
>     LU-1311
>     Luxembourg
>
> Registrar:
>     Amazon.com [Tag = AMAZON-COM]
>     URL: http://www.amazon.com
>
> Relevant dates:
>     Registered on: before Aug-1996
>     Expiry date:  05-Dec-2020
>     Last updated:  23-Oct-2013
> ```

I want this:

> ```
>     65 boulevard G-D. Charlotte
>     Luxembourg City
>     Luxembourg
>     LU-1311
>     Luxembourg
> ```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: 1. I want to use RegEx, because I store the expression in a DB.
2. I use SingleLine and IgnoreCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex to match only the data you need without capturing unnecessary data.

Using lookaround assertions:

```
(?<=Registrant's address:).*(?=(?:Registrar:|Registered:))
```

Working example:

http://regex101.com/r/cN5wP3

just make sure to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

**EDIT:**

And to capture the match in the named group `value` you would have this:

```
(?<=Registrant's address:)(?<value>.*)(?=(?:Registrar:|Registered:))
```

Example:

http://regex101.com/r/fY3oR9

Comment: This works good, but how can I use this with my Group "Value"?

Comment: `(?<=Registrant's address:)(?<value>.*)(?=(?:Registrar:|Registered:))`

Comment: With this (?<=Registrant's address:)(?<Value>.*)(?=(?:Registrar:|Registered)) the second data example doen't work. i got this http://pastebin.com/d8bKVGTS with the tool of a friend http://software.dhcgn.de/RegExTester/ which used die RegEx Option SingleLine and IgnoreCAse

Comment: It works..  see the working example link http://regex101.com/r/fY3oR9 .  In your pastebin, you are missing some of your data..  It's missing the address title, `Registrant's address:`.  With the data you have in your pastebin it would not work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't need regex here

```
var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(filename)
                .SkipWhile(x => !x.StartsWith("Registrant's address:"))
                .Skip(1)
                .TakeWhile(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Comment: Maybe adding `.Select(s => s.Trim())` too? +1 BTW.

Comment: Thx, but I need to use RegEx

Answer (score 2):

The `:` in your regex simply isn't present in your text and you'll need to specify `RegexOptions.Singleline` if you haven't already to allow `.` to match new lines.

```
Registrant's address:(\s*)(?<Value>.*).*((Registrar)|(Registered))
```

You have many capture groups that probably are unnecessary.

```
Registrant's address:\s*(?<Value>.*).*Regist(?:rar|ered)
```

Another note, you might hit some problem with greedy matching if you have consecutive records in the text you are trying to match. Adding a few `?` will solve the problem:

```
Registrant's address:\s*(?<Value>.*?).*?Regist(?:rar|ered)
```

Comment: Oops, my fault. I introduced an error in your regex my mistake. It should be `Regist(?:rar|ered)` instead. My bad! D:

Comment: @Jerry And I shouldn't copy-paste anything without double checking ;)

Comment: Thx, but I didn't get the rigth results if i try the second input. I use the Options SingleLine and IgnoreCase.

Comment: I friend wrote me this http://software.dhcgn.de/RegExTester/publish.htm so I can test RegEx Expressions. It used SingleLine and IgnoreCase. And with this the 2nde data example doesn't work. I don't know how to post code in the comment box. So I posted it here http://pastebin.com/1RG68WKz

Comment: @user1776231 It works for me here: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=d2a12d41-675d-4a91-8b1f-f2fed6c4ea6b